# Will wifi dongles work on installation?

Tags: wireless

I have a D-Link wifi dongle that I use to connect to the internet. I have not installed Ubuntu yet, and wanted to clear out that my dongle will work when installing Ubuntu, and after it is installed. It is the WUA2340.

Comment: You'll have to try this out: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=861855

Comment: See [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2304617&p=13398333#post13398333) to get us the info from Windows

Comment: Here's what I have... https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_66tkFLM4VWbEhISHhwRGZBTE0/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

It should work under Ubuntu and use the ar5523 kernel module for wifi.  I checked the kernel for your device and got

```
modprobe -c | grep -i 3a08
alias usb:v07D1p3A08ddcdscdpiciscipin ar5523
```

Comment: How do I edit the kernel? I'm very new to the Linux world, and have no experience with it what So ever.

Comment: You shouldn't have to do anything to the kernel.  Download an Ubuntu ISO and burn it to a DVD, boot it and select "Try Ubuntu" and see for yourself

Comment: Sweet! Thanks for your help! Will do it later.